# Bootstrap collapse's, only one working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

This code below makes all the collapse's visible but anyone that you click just opens and closes the very first one generated. How can I make them all open separately?

```
<a href="#demo" data-toggle="collapse">Comments</a> 
<div id="demo" class="collapse">
  <% @comments.each do |z| %>
    <% if z.post_id == post.id %>
      <%= z.name %> Commented: <%= z.body %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: use postid in class = "collapse-#{post.id}"

Answer (score 0):

i think you are missing the correct IDs to make them collapse

See below example. demo opens the id="#demo" and demo1 opens the #demo1

```
<a href="#demo" data-toggle="collapse">Collapsible1</a>
<a href="#demo1" data-toggle="collapse">Collapsible2</a>

<div id="demo" class="collapse">
  Collapse1
</div>
<div id="demo1" class="collapse">
  collapse2
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Needed to use the post.id for the collpase id.

```
<a href="#<%= post.id %>" data-toggle="collapse">Comments</a> 
<div id="<%=post.id %>" class="collapse">
  <% @comments.each do |z| %>
  <% if z.post_id == post.id %>
    <%= z.name %> Commented: <%= z.body %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```